# How do I prevent HTML5 game from suspending?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, suspend, construct

I am making an HTML5 game with Construct 2 and face one little problem: once I switch tab I get my game paused(suspended)

I have cleared the default engine suspension by calling "cr_setSuspended = function() {}" and now I don't receive messages about it in the log, but the game pauses anyway.

Maybe there is some browser stuff that suspends it automatically and I can prevent it? Please help me to find a solution

Comment: Browsers take power-saving measures when tabs are backgrounded. Animation frames and setInterval calls are severely throttled by design and it's rude to circumvent this (if it's even possible). I guess this all comes down to whether timing in your app is "frame" based or clock-time based.

Comment: Thanks, there are some clock-based events I need to be running on the background. I will try to get rid of them

Answer (score -1):

If I avoid all the timers, "wait" and "every x seconds" events and use triggers only everything works fine, even for Photon multiplayer